# Does OfficeJS outlook supports get body content as ooxml, text range selection, content control?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have officeJS word addin that has similar functionality to Grammarly. so, I need to integrate the same for the outlook web addin. Is there any possibilities to acheive the same in outlook because most of the methods which we use are from the word API isn't available in outlook API like getRange, get the body as ooxml, search by paragraph?
Are there any alternative methods to achieve the text range selection and highlight?

Answer (score 0):

No, the document APIs in Word.js are not supported in Outlook.js. Its in our backlog, with an unknown timeline to enable similar APIs.